# Wildfly filesystem permission denied with apache

Tags: linux, apache, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am trying to deploy my application on a linux machine with wildfly 8.2.
When i try to write a file to the file system in the root directory it works without any problems but when i try to write to a path (permisson 777) where apache is in duty it always says permission denied. Anyone an idea?

Comment: The user your using doesn't have permissions to that directory.

Comment: i changed the user to "wildfly"